# Search an XML column for a value/string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

i am looking to search an XML column called ClaimData in a SQL BatchProcessedClaims table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BatchProcessedClaims](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Im] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ClaimData] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Below is the value contained in one cell

```
<BGMSG>
<HEADER COMPLETION="Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35">
<ROUTING_SLIP>
<RECIPIENT Channel=".\private$\q_amb_leg" Delivered="1" DeliveryTime="2014-06-21T16:40:07.298" />
  <RECIPIENT Channel=".\private$\22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35" Delivered="0" />
</ROUTING_SLIP>
</HEADER>
</BGMSG>
```

i am searching for all records with "Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35". i am trying it in 3 different ways
method 1

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [BATCHES].[dbo].[BatchProcessedClaims]
WHERE ClaimData.value('(/BGMSG/HEADER)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') LIKE 'Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35'
```

method 2

```
SELECT TOP 10 ClaimData.query('/BGMSG/HEADER[@COMPLETION="Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35"]')
FROM [BATCHES].[dbo].[BatchProcessedClaims]
```

method 3

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM (
    SELECT pref.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(75)') AS Batchname
    FROM BatchProcessedClaims
    CROSS APPLY ClaimData.nodes('/BGMSG/HEADER') AS ClaimData(pref)
    ) AS Result
WHERE Batchname LIKE 'Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35'
```

Method 1 runs for 6 minutes and Method 3 runs for like 13 minutes and gives no results and method 2 gives me 10 blank records as results. What am i doing wrong

i tried method 4

```
SELECT top 10 * 
FROM   BatchProcessedClaims 
WHERE  CONTAINS(ClaimData,'Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35') 
AND    xCol.exist('/BGMSG/HEADER/text()[contains(.,"Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35")]') =1
```

but i currently do not have full-text indexed and i get an error 
"Msg 7601, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'BatchProcessedClaims' because it is not full-text indexed."

i am trying to accomplish with out enabling full-text indexed by method 1 to 3

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these should work fairly efficiently:

```
select top 10 * from BatchProcessedClaims
where claimdata.value('(/BGMSG/HEADER/@COMPLETION)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35'
```

OR

```
select top 10 * from BatchProcessedClaims
where claimdata.exist('/BGMSG/HEADER[@COMPLETION[1] = "Batch_22e3bc5f-d130-4a28-b078-4f3416360a35"]') = 1
```

The `exist` version *should* be faster, but you'll want to test against your dataset.